# Can I add a slightly altered function from another R package to my own R package?

Tags: r, r-package

I am working on a R package of my own which contains a function that needs as input an output of a function, say, functionA, from another package. It's a relatively simple function of about 30 lines of R code. The problem is that for my function I need additional output from functionA which is computed within the functionA but which is not provided in the output of functionA. Therefore I was thinking of creating a new function to my package (basically a copy-paste of functionA) but then where the output object also contains that additional element. Now my question is whether it would be sufficient to only acknowledge the original functionA or do I have to make the whole R base team who developed functionA coauthor of my package? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some related reading [from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) and [Hadley Wickham's R Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#author). I have seen different approaches to this sort of thing, but (with of course imperfect recall) believe I have more often seen those who acknowledge the original function contributed by the base R team without adding them as co-authors. Depending on the extent to which you are reusing their code, I have seen people list them as contributors though.

Comment: I see two issues here: (1) Where to cite: There are two appropriate places to acknowledge your source: the documentation of the particular function, and the package description file. (Okay, a third would be as comments in the code of the function itself. If you're using roxygen and documenting the function in the code file, this would be redundant.) (2) Who to cite: R Core, list the whole base R team, something else?

Comment: For (1), personally, I think you should add citation in the function documentation but not the DESCRIPTION file---I wouldn't want to be listed as a contributor for a package without explicit consent because it could easily imply endorsement; I would hope someone would send me an email asking first. You can use an `@author` roxygen tag for this, and note that you adapted the function from the original by X.

Comment: Do try to identify a specific author. `?nls`, for example, is in the `stats` package by identifies specific function authors in the documentation. If you're unable to identify specific author(s), especially with the size of the R Core team, it seems reasonable to just acknowledge the group. Definitely look at the `citation` defined for the package, e.g., `citation("stats")`, which lists the author as "R Core Team".

Comment: But these are just like, my opinions, man. Unless someone can reference more direct guidance somewhere, hopefully from R Core, I would suggest asking on the [r-package-devel mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel) and adding an answer here referencing the response you get.